# Tax Calculator - Vb.net

Tags: vb.net

So I'm making a program that the user enters his name, hours worked, and the rate of his pay and clicks calculate. It would then return the taxes for the following:

Gross Pay - Pay before taxes.

FICA - 8% of the gross pay.

FTW - Calculated by multiplying the gross pay by 20%.

State Income Tax - 2% of Gross Pay.

Net Pay - Total pay after taxes.

I tried this, but it's not working for me.
Private Sub cmdSubmit_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSubmit.Click

```
    Dim add, add2, add3, add4 As Integer

    add = Val(txtPrice1.Text)
    add2 = Val(txtPrice2.Text)
    add3 = Val(txtPrice3.Text)
    add4 = Val(txtPrice4.Text)

    lblTest.Text = Format(add + add2 + add3 + add4, "currency")
    lblTest2.Text = Format(lblTest.Text * 0.06 + lblTest.Text, "currency")
End Sub
```

I know that you would use .txt and Val, but I'm confused as to how I would program this.

Answer (score 2):

You should try using Decimals instead of Integers.

You should try using Decimal.TryParse instead of Val().

You should try using a variable for the sum.

You should try using a variable to calculate the 0.06 multiplier.

```
Dim add, add2, add3, add4 As Decimal

If Not Decimal.TryParse(txtPrice1.Text, add) Then
  MessageBox.Show("Bad Number")
End If
etc...

Dim total As Decimal = add + add2 + add3 + add4
Dim amount As Decimal = (total * 0.06) + total

lblTest.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", total)
lblTest2.Text = String.Format("{0:C}", amount)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using some Constants to help clean things up and it would make it easier to change the tax rates if in the future they change.

```
Const cdecFICA as Decimal = 0.08D
Const cdecFTW as Decimal = 0.20D
Const cdecState as Decimal = 0.02D
Dim decFICA as Decimal
Dim decFTW as Decimal
Dim decState as Decimal
Dim decNetPay as Decimal
Dim decGrossIncome as Decimal

'Use your tryparse statement here'

decGrossIncome = txtHours.text * txtPayRate.text
decFICA = decGrossIncome* cdecFICA
decFTW = decGrossIncome* cdecFTW
decState = decGrossIncome* cdecState
decNetPay = decGrossIncome - decFICA - decFTW - decState
```

This can all be done on one line, but setting it up this way will allow you to show each tax total and use them how you see fit.

I have had to create programs that needed me to display all of the tax values next to their respected label, then calculate the Net pay after taxes.

Its good to use decimals to calculate as it holds more significant numbers to calculate with, what you can do when you display this total is convert the final decimal number into a string to make it more meaningful to the end user. Such as:

```
lblName.text = decNetPay.ToString("C2")
```

so it will display as a currency value with 2 significant figures.

Edit:

Upon submitting, I have seen that this was a very old thread. =/